# How to Join on only 1 rows of first table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables t1 and t2. Both table has 3 matching column. t1 has 10 rows of those 3 matching column whereas t2 has 12 matching rows. When I use left join, i get 120 rows for 3 matching column. I would like to get similar number of matching rows like 12 rows after joining. That means I need to join on only 1 rows of first table. Ho to do it? My query is below:

```
select t1.*,t2.*
from t1
left join
t2 
on t1.column1 = t2.column1
and t1.column2 = t2.column2
and t1.column3 = t2.column3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L0v0.png)

Comment: please show some sample data and desired results

Comment: @ Felipe, please see the image in the question. here I want to use 2 matching column.

Comment: From the example attached  I see only two matching columns between the tables. Can you explain more in detail join logic here?